# Kvaser Leaf Light CAN BUS Simulator problems

Tags: simulation, automotive, can, bus

I'm learning to use this tool [Kvaser Leaf Light V2](http://www.kvaser.com/products/kvaser-leaf-light-v2/) with CAN-BUS. I'm stuck with some problems. I can read the packets around the CAN-BUS line from the car, I can save it in a text file, but when I want to resend this on my "Own CAN-BUS" that's connected to my instrument cluster, the instrument cluster doesnt do anything (it just turns on the digital clock)... is there any "Ignition" or "Turn on" packet that I'm missing?

Info:
Car: Fiat Stilo 1.8 petrol
Baud rate: 50k

**Update 1**(17/01/2015):

Info about how I'm using CANKing:

*1st way*, "Custom messaging" on my own CANBUS Trunk:
I click on Messages>Universal>Universal and I write my message in the field:
For example I want to manipulate RPMs I send 
7E8 | 0x04 | 0x41 | 0x0C | 0x0D | 0x50 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00
(What's supposed to be what car sends to nodes informating about RPM)
But Instrument cluster doesnt do anything and I get Error frame message.

*2nd Way*, Logged file messages: 
Well, I dont know if it should be working, but I tried also with no success;
I sniffed data from the car (Fiat Stilo 1.8i) and logged to a file, with some variants (Turn on ignition, turn off, accelerating, etc. All while recording it)

Once I recorded, I did use:
View>History List>Load..[I load here my recorded file]>Send All

I think this should simulate the car system and the Instrument cluster should replicate what I was seeing in the car or I'm wrong?

**Update 1.1**(17/01/2015):
I will change resistances also, I misunderstanded the concept, I will get 120Ohm ones and feedback with it, someone that's helping me, told me that I'm missing Ground Kvaser to Ground Inst. Cluster.

**Update 2.0 (18/01/2015):
I changed resistances to 120Ohm, wired Kvaser GND to Instrument tool GND, and I managed to light up my Speedometer with the RPM gauge (Fault was that speedometer box got more than one 12V+ in, as it has different modules). But I can't manage to work it.
I want to control RPM and Speedometer gauges, but when i send any message, i get like 700~ error frame messages... the same when I start sending text file with all the traffic I recorded...

Anyone know where can I find FIAT CAN DB or can point me in right direction? Thanks.

[image: "Schema":]

Comment: I sometimes use [CANKing](http://www.kvaser.com/canking/) at work to send CAN-messages out on a CAN bus without any problems, but CANKing can be a little unintuitive to operate. Can you describe *exactly* how you operate the program (by editing your question)?

Comment: Try to apply what is in the answer. Do you still get error frames then?

Comment: Hi @PeterMortensen , I tried to fill the topic with all Info I could, if I'm missing anything, please tell me, you are very helpful to me, thanks!

Comment: The way you send messages using CANking seems to be OK.

Comment: The message you send, 7E8 | 0x04 | 0x41 | 0x0C | 0x0D | 0x50 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00, is very important information for answering this question.

Comment: That message is suppossed to be Car sending RPM to all nodes in the bus, 7E8 is the ID, 0x04 the following bytes, 0x41 is actual data, 0x0C says it's RPM, and 0x0D and 0x50 the bytes to use in the formula for RPM = ((Byte3*256)+Byte4)/4= 856RPM. (That's what instrument cluster should show..)

Comment: [Instrument cluster](http://media.clusterrepairsuk.co.uk/images/repairs/fiat_stilo_instrument_cluster_speedo_mk1_1312502157_big.pjpeg)

Comment: I am not familiar with that protocol (only [CANopen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CANopen)), but [7E8 may be *"Physical response CAN identifier from ECU #1 to external test equipment"*](http://osdir.com/ml/hardware.bus.can/2005-09/msg00075.html).

Answer (score 5):

### The termination is not correct

The termination resistors' values are too low. They should be 120 ohm, not 60 ohm (for a *total* ohmic resistance of 60 ohm - if you measure between CAN-H and CAN-L with a multimeter with *all power off* you should get 60 ohm. At the moment you would measure 30 ohm).

### Lonely CAN bus device

If "Fiat Stilo instrument cluster" only contains a single device, it is important that the CAN adapter is participating on the CAN bus (for example, setting the [ACK bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus#ACK_slot)). In [CANKing](http://www.kvaser.com/canking/) this is done by setting *Driver Mode* to *Normal* (not *Silent*):

[image: Screenshot from CANking, window "CAN Controller"]

However, as this is the default setting, it is probably already set to *Normal*. If the actual Kvaser adapter does not support silent mode then the setting does not matter if the version of CANking is sufficiently new, version 5.0 or later (2009-06-09).

Comment: I would like to answer other parts of the question, but I am missing information.

Comment: It's already connected as Normal Mode, and CanKing version should be the newest, as I bought 1 week ago and installed their web drivers.